# Time between on campus interview and tenure track job offer

Tags: faculty-application, tenure-track, interview

I would like to know how much time it can take for a department to make an offer after an on-campus interview for a tenure track assistant professor position? In my field the on-campus interview is the second interview that follows the phone interview. This is about universities in the U.S.

Comment: What type of position is this for (PhD, postdoc, tenure track etc)?

Comment: Tenure track assistant professor position

Comment: It depends entirely on the university. Also, note that they won't notify anybody of the decision until the first-choice candidate has accepted or rejected the offer. And, if they reject, they'll wait until the second-choice candidate accepts or rejects.  And, if they reject, ... So it can take a while.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no clear and well-bounded answer.  In general, however, you should anticipate the time to be on the order of months.

To understand why, consider these typical components of process:

- After your interview, a number of other candidates may be coming to interview.
- Once all of the candidates interview, the faculty needs to decide who they want to hire. This may happen in multiple stages (e.g., first a search committee triages down to the top candidates, then the full department chooses between them).
- A formal offer is prepared for the top candidate and negotiated amongst the department and any other involved university organizations (e.g., HR, deans, centers, etc.).
- The candidate has some weeks to decide whether to accept the offer, possibly including more negotiations and revisions to the offer.
- If the candidate says no, things begin again with offer preparation, negotiation, and decision for the next candidate.

Every one of these steps is likely to take on the order of weeks, so you can see how it can easily add up to multiple months.

Comment: The time frame can't be too long, because if the department waits too long, all of the candidates will have taken other jobs.

Comment: @PeterShor Oh, certainly (taking "all the candidates" to mean "all the really good candidates")---but between some interviews starting early and some choices resolving late, it's quite possible for the delay to stretch into the 4-6 month timeframe.

Comment: I'm currently witnessing a search for a new professor that has already taken well over a year (without anyone found yet, so it might still take a few more years...), because of this very reason: The whole process takes just too much time, it all has to be very official and the university is not allowed to contact the second person on the list until negotiations have failed once and for all with the first one (which might take months)... So as long as you are not top of the list, you should at least think in months, maybe even years.

Comment: Would a follow up email with the results of their search be helpful?

Comment: @Change I'm afraid that I don't know what you're asking: do you mean you want them to email you, or that you're considering emailing them?

Comment: I've already emailed the chair of the search committee and asked about the results. I was given a generic answer that they sent their recommendations to human resources and adminstration. The chair of the search committee stated that she is not allowed to say more than that. I will continue to wait for another week and then the answer will become clearer.

Comment: I am still waiting though. The search committee chair says that contacting references is the job of HR. My references are still waiting to hear from them. Is it common that HR contact references after the committee search gave it's recommendation about a candidate?

Comment: I'm baffled. The search committee should really have the references before they make any recommendations. They obviously do things different at this department than the ones I'm familiar with.